# How to throw an error in the outer function from an inner async function like setTimeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, settimeout, throw

i want to sign in to in my react native app using firebase authentication. For example, to login with email and password i have the following function, which is basically a redux action:

```
export const userSignin = (email, password) =>
  async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'auth_attempt_started' })
      const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
      saveUserDataToAsyncStorage(user)
      if (!TASKS_SORT_BY && !TASKS_SORT_ORDER)
        dispatch(getTasksSortData(user.user.uid))
      if (!EMPLOYEES_SORT_BY && !EMPLOYEES_SORT_ORDER)
        dispatch(getEmployeesSortData(user.user.uid))
      if (!ACCOUNTS_SORT_BY && !ACCOUNTS_SORT_ORDER)
        dispatch(getAccountsSortData(user.user.uid))
      goToMain()
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'user_signedin',
          payload: user
        })
      }, 100);
    }
    catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'auth_error',
        payload: err.toString()
      })
    }
  }
```

This function throw an error if something went wrong with the signin process. 
The problem is **when the internet connection is slow**, the signin process take a long time before the success or the failure, sometimes around 30 seconds which is very bad for the user experience.

The question is:

**How can i throw an error after sometimes maybe 10 seconds if the signin process does not complete?**

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it can be achieved with setTimeout.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setTimeout( () => {
     this.doThisAfterTenSeconds();
  },10000);
}

doThisAfterTenSeconds() {
   // Do something
}
```

In this particular scenario,

```
export const userSignin = (email, password) =>
  async dispatch => {
    try {
      // Auth attempt has started
      dispatch({ type: 'auth_attempt_started' })

      // Lets add a 10 second timeout
      let hasTimedOut = false
      setTimeout(() => {
          hasTimedOut = true
          // Display message here or throw "Connection timed out"
      }, 10000)

      // Now lets await the authentication
      const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
      // This code should not be run if auth attempt timed out. If we throw an error the check should not be neccessary...
      if (!hasTimedOut)
      {
         saveUserDataToAsyncStorage(user)
         if (!TASKS_SORT_BY && !TASKS_SORT_ORDER)
           dispatch(getTasksSortData(user.user.uid))
         if (!EMPLOYEES_SORT_BY && !EMPLOYEES_SORT_ORDER)
           dispatch(getEmployeesSortData(user.user.uid))
         if (!ACCOUNTS_SORT_BY && !ACCOUNTS_SORT_ORDER)
           dispatch(getAccountsSortData(user.user.uid))
         goToMain()
         setTimeout(() => {
           dispatch({
             type: 'user_signedin',
             payload: user
           })
         }, 100);
         }
       }
       catch (err) {
         dispatch({
           type: 'auth_error',
           payload: err.toString()
         })
       }
     }
```

Comment: Yes but if I throw an error in the setTimeout function, the main function will keep running until the const user = awai ... is done; if the promise is resolved the function will end because it will not execute the next if block, but if The await user promise was rejected an other error will be thrown in the main catch block.. how to handle such case?

Comment: Hi @HadiYakhni, I did some research and this seems like a nice solution for what you need to do: https://italonascimento.github.io/applying-a-timeout-to-your-promises/ basically use Promise.race(promiseA, promiseB), where one of the promises is a timeout and the other is the actual promise you need to implement.

Comment: Thankyou @RandallValenciano, great solution!